# Displaying my timer readout in a separate view

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I am new to this and need to be pointed in the right direction. I have a simple stopwatch app that allows the user to make inputs for the start time via a datepicker.

I want the readout of MM:SS to be displayed in a separate view (view 1) from the datepicker (view 2).

What should I search in order to learn how to do this? Right now it is all on a single view.

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to accomplish this - are you using NIB/Storyboard, or generating the view via code and doing `[self.view addSubview:datepicker]`? Also, are you currently showing the MM:SS in view 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using following method :

In View1 controller use this :

```
-(void)timerupdate
{
   int minutes=10;
   int seconds =10;

 NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d", minutes, seconds],@"mytime", nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"anyname" object:self userInfo:dict];
}
```

In View2 controller use this :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                                 selector: @selector(anymethod:)
                                                     name: @"anyname"
                                                   object: nil];

    }

    - (void)anymethod:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
     NSLog(@"%@",[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"mytime"]);

     }
```

Hope this will help you..I use this for me and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a mechanism to pass data in between different UIViews (UIViewControllers).

1. Worse option would be to implement a singleton using singleton pattern. Then pass your data back and forth using delegation.
2. or create a custom class to store the date what you want and pass it to every time when you are changing your UIView or UIViewController.